# /bin/bash behavior in container shell and dockerfile

Tags: docker, shell, dockerfile

I'm new to dockerfile and I have a hard time running a simple check command present in an image.

When I run a container with this image, I'm seeing this behavior from the shell (/bin/sh):

```
$ /bin/bash -c foamVersion
/bin/bash: foamVersion: command not found
$ /bin/bash
nextfoam@3ab61c950023:/home$ foamVersion
OpenFOAM-6
```

I'm running it from /bin/sh because this image seems to use it by default (Ubuntu 18).

My goal is to do get foamVersion result. Here's the dockerfile:

```
FROM nextfoam/baram6:latest
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN foamVersion
```

On host (Ubuntu 21.10), I run:

```
docker build -t mybaram:latest .
[+] Building 0.3s (5/5) FINISHED                                                        
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 384B                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/nextfoam/baram6:latest                  0.0s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/nextfoam/baram6:latest                             0.0s
 => ERROR [2/2] RUN foamVersion                                                    0.3s
------
 > [2/2] RUN foamVersion:
#5 0.242 /bin/bash: foamVersion: command not found
```

type foamVersion

```
foamVersion is a function
foamVersion () 
{ 
    if [ "$1" ]; then
        foamInstDir=$FOAM_INST_DIR;
        . $WM_PROJECT_DIR/etc/config.sh/unset;
        . $foamInstDir/OpenFOAM-$1/etc/bashrc;
        cd $WM_PROJECT_DIR;
        echo "Changed to OpenFOAM-$1" 1>&2;
    else
        echo "OpenFOAM-$WM_PROJECT_VERSION" 1>&2;
    fi
}
```

Any idea how to get foamVersion working from build process in dockerfile?

Comment: Please post the output of `type foamVersion`. Where is the code for `formaVersion` stored? Where does it come form? What is the dockerfile of `nextfoam`?

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk, `nextfoam/baram6` is public on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/nextfoam/baram6), I can't find `whereis foamVersion` though, and I don't have the dockerfile of it (this one would have greatly helped).

Comment: Great - it's a function. Now you have to find where does it come from, where is it defined. A stupid way is to run `grep -R foamVersion /` within the container and wait. Maybe try running `bash -lx` and browse logs. You can also just run your stuff in a login shell.

Comment: `grep -R foamVersion / | more` is throwing too many results (not stoping at each page), I also tried it at /opt/openfoam and the most interesting candidates are: `./bin/foamExec:#     Runs the <foamVersion> version of executable <foamCommand>`, `./etc/config.sh/aliases:foamVersion()`

Comment: But more globally, how could I run /bin/bash commands in dockerfile like when I'm in the container shell?

Comment: `how could I run /bin/bash commands in dockerfile like when I'm in the container shell?` `expect` allows for tty inteaction. `is throwing too many results (not stoping at each page)` sure, you have to find a definition. Try like `grep -ER 'foamVersion[[:space:]]*\(\)'` or `'function[[:space:]]*foamVersion'` or just ask the author or try to inspect docker layers.